# Show list of values in one sheet which are not in the other

Tags: google-sheets

I have a pretty basic problem (I guess) and would be glad if anybody could help me

I have two Sheets in on spreadsheet. One Sheet contains serial numbers, as well as other information (relevant id's, etc). In the other sheet, I have a plain list of serial numbers. In this sheet I want to have a list of those serial numbers which AREN'T in the first sheet.

I'm pretty lost right now. 
First time really working with Excel/Spreadsheets

Comment: You can use COUNTIF or MATCH to accomplish this.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your serial numbers in spreadsheet with ID `xxxxxx` are in `Sheet1` in cells `D1:D` and in your other sheets your plain list is in cells `E2:E22`,
you can use

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(E2:E6, ISNA(MATCH(E2:E22, IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","Sheet1!D1:D"), 0))))
```

It is good practice to first give rights to `IMPORTRANGE` to connect your first sheet with the `xxxxxx` ID to your second one and then use it in the formula.
Keep in mind that since we use `IMPORTRANGE` you may occasionally (for maybe a couple of seconds) see a `#N/A` message. It will go away after the 2 sheets synchronize.

Functions used:

- [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)
- [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)
- [`ISNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)